# arecord does not work with crontab

Tags: sound, cron

I am having a problem with cron job recordings. I can run arecord from tcsh scripts as the same user as the GUI from a terminal, but it will not run from crontab. The crontab user is the same as the GUI. The arecord will write 44 bytes of the output .wav file and the stop forever. I have to use kill -9 to stop the process.

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: Can you run `arecord --version` and `arecord -L` in terminal and post results  ?

Comment: sound@sound20150823:~> arecord --version
arecord: version 1.0.27.2 by Jaroslav Kysela <perex@perex.cz>

Comment: sound@sound20150823:~> arecord -L
default
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
sysdefault:CARD=PCH
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC662 rev1 Analog
    Default Audio Device

Comment: There is an environmental variable called XDG_RUNTIME_DIR that needs to be setup before you invoke the arecord command. I set mine to "setenv XDG_RUNTIME_DIR /run/user/${euid}". Also, arecord uses "pulseaudio" to interface the hardware. This requires you to login in using the GUI with the same username as established by ${euid}. Go into setup and select your input source and input level BEFORE the crontab execution begins. I know this is clunky, but it works. I eagerly await a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

There is an environmental variable called XDG_RUNTIME_DIR that needs to be setup before you invoke the arecord command. I set mine to "setenv XDG_RUNTIME_DIR /run/user/${euid}". Also, arecord uses "pulseaudio" to interface the hardware. This requires you to login in using the GUI with the same username as established by ${euid}. Go into setup and select your input source and input level BEFORE the crontab execution begins. I know this is clunky, but it works. I eagerly await a better solution.

Comment: As I have `Command 'setenv' not found` on 22.04.2, I solved the issue on Mint by using `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u) arecord`.